# 404 Bad request of URL for downloading a fiel in Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following code, I want to download the files stored in my Firebase Storage:

```
const downloadFile = (url, filename) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    console.log(url)
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
    link.remove();
 };
```

Pulling the files:

```
try {
      const files = [];
            const listRef = ref(storage, `files/events/${path}/thumnails`);
            const {items} = await listAll(listRef);
            for (const itemRef of items) {
                const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(itemRef);

                await downloadFile(downloadURL, itemRef.name);
                files.push(
                        {
                            imgName: itemRef.name,
                            imgUrl: downloadURL
                        }
                    );
            }
            setImages(files);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
```

I get the following error:

> 404 Bad request
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boda-1c364.appspot.com/o/files/events/x5JlZKysM7NhXx1Awv6ljGY3jUA2/thumnails/9ED15BA2-A95B-4A2E-8BF5-24743F8FCF8B_200x200.jpeg?alt=media&token=ee3c5679-a17c-4a63-b650-506fd1fde654

This is what appears in my img tag after the downloadLinkUrl has been set as the img src, and the image does display correctly.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/boda-1c364.appspot.com/o/files%2Fevents%2Fx5JlZKysM7NhXx1Awv6ljGY3jUA2%2Fthumnails%2F9ED15BA2-A95B-4A2E-8BF5-24743F8FCF8B_200x200.jpeg?alt=media&token=ee3c5679-a17c-4a63-b650-506fd1fde654

Answer (score -1):

There's a boo-boo in your file download function...

```
const downloadFile = (url, filename) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    console.log(url)
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
    link.remove();   <-- comment this line out
 };
```

You create a temp element which is not written to the DOM and is fine, but then attempt to remove it from the DOM when it hasn't been added to it!

Comment: How would this cause a "404 Bad request" HTTP error?

Comment: It’s a different bug he needs to eliminate, so there’s more than one problem.

Comment: The question is pretty clear what the problem is that needs to be solved - what you have here is unrelated and not even necessarily a bug (a bug is only really a bug if it has an unexpected effect on the outcome).  In fact, the remove has no effect at all, and commenting it out will do nothing to change the outcome of the code.

Comment: The 404 seems like a refusal. No authentication needed… really? I wonder…

Comment: No, 404 means "not found". It has nothing to do with auth. Firebase Storage download URLs should work for anyone who has the URL.

Comment: Btw, await should be used in async functions, but I don’t see any promises in the script posted.

Comment: `await` does nothing with values that aren't promises. That won't cause problems, even if it reads incorrectly.